# Dynamic columns in SQL statement

Tags: postgresql, variables, triggers, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I am trying to have a dynamic variable that I can specify different column's with (depending on some if statements). Explained in code, I am trying to replace this:

```
IF (TG_TABLE_NAME='this') THEN INSERT INTO table1 (name_id) VALUES id.NEW END IF;
IF (TG_TABLE_NAME='that') THEN INSERT INTO table1 (lastname_id) VALUES id.NEW END IF;
IF (TG_TABLE_NAME='another') THEN INSERT INTO table1 (age_id) VALUES id.NEW END IF;
```

With this:

```
DECLARE
varName COLUMN;
BEGIN
IF (TG_TABLE_NAME='this') THEN varName = 'name_id'; 
ELSE IF (TG_TABLE_NAME='that') THEN varName = 'lastname_id'; 
ELSE (TG_TABLE_NAME='another') THEN varName = 'age_id';
END IF;

INSERT INTO table1 (varName) VALUES id.NEW;
END;
```

The INSERT string is just an example, it's actually something longer. I am a beginner at pgSQL. I've seen some examples but I'm only getting more confused. If you can provide an answer that is also more safe from SQL injection that would be awesome.

Comment: What's `pgSQL` supposed to be? There is *PostgreSQL* (or *Postgres* for short), *psql* (the command-line interface) and *plpgsql* (the procedural server-side language) ... Obviously, you are working on a trigger function. When asking about a **plpgsql** function, please always provide the *complete* function including header and footer, which are integral parts.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do what you're looking for is to compose your `INSERT` statement dynamically based on the named table.  The following function approximates the logic you laid out in the question:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION smart_insert(table_name TEXT) RETURNS VOID AS $$
  DECLARE
    target TEXT;
    statement TEXT;
  BEGIN
    CASE table_name
      WHEN 'this' THEN target := 'name_id';
      WHEN 'that' THEN target := 'lastname_id';
      WHEN 'another' THEN target := 'age_id';
    END CASE;
    statement :=
      'INSERT INTO '||table_name||'('||target||') VALUES (nextval(''id''));';   
    EXECUTE statement;
  END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Note that I'm using a sequence to populate these tables (the call to `nextval`).  I'm not sure if that is your use case, but hopefully this example is extensible enough for you to modify it to fit your scenario.  A contrived demo:

```
postgres=# SELECT smart_insert('this');
 smart_insert
--------------

(1 row)

postgres=# SELECT smart_insert('that');
 smart_insert
--------------

(1 row)

postgres=# SELECT name_id FROM this;
 name_id
---------
     101
(1 row)

postgres=# SELECT lastname_id FROM that;
 lastname_id
-------------
         102
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example doesn't make a lot of sense. Probably over-simplified. Anyway, here is a **trigger function** for the requested functionality that inserts the new `id` in a selected column of a target table, depending on the triggering table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION smart_insert(table_name TEXT)
  RETURNS trigger AS
$func$
BEGIN
   EXECUTE
   'INSERT INTO table1 ('
    || CASE TG_TABLE_NAME
        WHEN 'this'    THEN 'name_id'
        WHEN 'that'    THEN 'lastname_id'
        WHEN 'another' THEN 'age_id'
       END CASE
    ||') VALUES ($1)'
   USING NEW.id;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

- To refer to the `id` column of the new row, use `NEW.id` not <strike>`id.NEW`</strike>.
- To pass a *value* to dynamic code, use [the `USING` clause of `EXECUTE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN). This is faster and more elegant, avoids casting to `text` and back and also makes SQL injection impossible.
- Don't use many variables and assignments in plpgsql, where this is comparatively expensive.

If the listed columns of the target table don't have non-default column defaults, you don't even need dynamic SQL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION smart_insert(table_name TEXT)
  RETURNS trigger AS
$func$
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO table1 (name_id, lastname_id, age_id)
   SELECT CASE WHEN TG_TABLE_NAME = 'this'    THEN NEW.id END
        , CASE WHEN TG_TABLE_NAME = 'that'    THEN NEW.id END
        , CASE WHEN TG_TABLE_NAME = 'another' THEN NEW.id END;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

A `CASE` expression without `ELSE` clause defaults to `NULL`, which is the default column default.

Both variants are safe against SQL injection.